# Linkify.js.org (jQuery) HashTags: Change the default URL destination to Twitter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, custom-data-attribute, linkify

I'm sanitizing CDATA content from various third-party XML feeds, stripping all HTML server-side and using [Linkify.js.org (v3.0.3)](https://linkify.js.org/) to safely reapply HTML tags to the sanitized plaintext links client-side.

My project relies a lot on [jQuery (v3.6.0)](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js).

The [linkify jQuery DOM Data API](https://linkify.js.org/docs/linkify-jquery.html#dom-data-api) is working great on links and email addresses, but hashtags are proving problematic. By default, hashtags redirect to `https://my-domain.com/current-dir/#<HashTag>`, but I'd like them to redirect to `https://twitter.com/hashtag/<HashTag>`. I know this is possible from the demo examples, but I'd like to stick with a jQuery solution, and maintain the div data attributes if possible.

I've read the documentation from [Linkify.js.org/docs/](https://linkify.js.org/docs/) but can't figure out how to change the hashtag URL without dropping the jQuery div data attributes.

Below is a simple example (it's important I maintain a `_blank` HREF target):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Linkify</title>
</head>
<body>
<div data-linkify="this" data-linkify-target="_blank">
  Domain Test: domain.com. Email Test: email@address.com. HashTag Test: #Linkify.
</div>
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/js/linkify.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/js/linkify-jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/js/linkify-plugin-hashtag.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Work's great, but as mentioned, #Linkify redirects to the same page (e.g; `https://my-domain.com/current-dir/#Linkify`).

Client-side JS is not my strong point, but is there a `data-linkify` attribute I can use to change the HashTag destination to Twitter? Or additional jQuery code I can use to modify the behaviour of the `linkify-plugin-hashtag.min.js` plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Use the hashtag plugin options... And since you do not want to call linkify directly, you'll need to play with the default options.

If you add this, it should work out.

```
linkify.options.defaults.formatHref.hashtag= (href) => 
    'https://twitter.com/hashtag/' + href.substr(1);
```

You can read more at https://linkify.js.org/docs/plugin-hashtag.html and https://linkify.js.org/docs/options.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I've spent hours experimenting with the hashtag plugin documentation, and no `linkify.options` code settings seems to be compatible when using `data-linkify="this"` as a `div` attribute.

If You could provide an example that would be perfect. I'll continue to experiment outside of jQuery and provide a solution if I find one. I'd just rather stick to jQuery, I'm so used to it, pure JavaScript just seems alien to me.

Comment: If you'd setup a working example I'd gladly do my best to help.

Comment: I've setup a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/83wvczLp/), I just copied and pasted the JS (jQuery minified. linkify.js, linkify-jquery.js, and linkify-plugin-hashtag.js non-minified). I'm not much of a front end developer so it might be a bit messy, I apologise 

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your HTML after `<script src="/js/linkify-plugin-hashtag.min.js"></script>`:

```html
<script>
linkify.options.defaults.formatHref = (href, type) =>
    type === 'hashtag' ? 'https://twitter.com/hashtag/' + href.substr(1) : href
</script>
```

This is a modification to @Salketer's code that should make this work with the latest version of Linkify.